# Cannot connect to instance with new user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I tried creating a user for a login with the below script, similar to the [steps indicated here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17180/29842):

```
CREATE LOGIN radu_test WITH PASSWORD = 'ABCD1234!!!!';

CREATE USER radu_test FOR LOGIN radu_test;

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.AccountInformation to radu_test;
```

And then tried to connect with this user in SSMS, but I'm getting the below error and I'm kind of stumped as to what to do next. I'm pretty sure this is a basic thing, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you executed the `CREATE LOGIN` on the `L-R900` server?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have. When trying to run this again: "Msg 15025, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The server principal 'radu_test' already exists.
Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
User, group, or role 'radu_test' already exists in the current database.
". And there is only one instance on this machine.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that you entered the password correctly (and you should not be posting passwords in a public forum)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Copy paste and entering it manually. Btw, the password is not the real one. Also the Server name is not the real one.

Comment: Check the instance's error log, ther will be more info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sql server (instance)  properties check the mixed authentication mode.  You must enable it in order to connect with a sql server login.